# how to enable confluent.value.schema.validation for cp-helm-charts

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry, helm3

I am using helm to deploy kafka using [cp-helm-charts](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts)

I have enabled zookeeper, kafka, schema registry and control center components. In control center UI I am able to create a topic and set a schema for the topic. However schema validation is not enabled and it is still possible to write arbitrary text to the topic.

I am trying to enable schema validation as [described here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/schema-validation.html)
by adding these options to my helm values:

```
cp-control-center:
  configurationOverrides:
    "confluent.schema.registry.url": http://data-cp-schema-registry:8081
    "confluent.value.schema.validation": true
```

But it has no effect.

QUESTION:
How to enable schema validation for cp-helm-charts kafka?
The idea is to restrict all the contents that does not match specified schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema validation is only applicable to Confluent Server (the broker), or the topics, not Control Center container, so you'll need to move that override to the kafka configuration instead (and verify it's using the `cp-server` image)

It's worth mentioning that that's a paid feature of Confluent Enterprise.